# Access image file in Metro JS project from WinRT component project

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-component

I am working on a JavaScript metro application, and I found out that to call a C# code from JavaScript I have to use Windows Runtime Component project in my solution. Now I need to check some image which are added in the JavaScript metro application in "images" folder and if they are there I need to copy them in the application local folder.

First I tried using the method

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/logo.png"))
```

but it throws exception that could not find the location/ file path.

I thought it might be because the namespaces of project are different. The image is added in JavaScript metro application project and I am trying to use it from a Windows Runtime Component project.

So I tried passing a hard coded path for the image file like "E://projects/myProject/myProject/images/logo.png", and tried with method

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(<passed the above path>);
```

but it throws exception that file path is not correct format.

Can I access a file added in JavaScript metro application project from Windows Runtime Component project in the same solution? And copy it in the application local folder?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, and I tried your first line of code in a new JS project with a new WinRT component in C#. It worked just fine. Can you show more of the whole C# class in your component as well as the JS code that's calling it?

Here's the .cs code for my test:

```
using System;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace Test2
{
    public sealed class Class1
    {
        public async void TestAccess()
        {
            StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/logo.png"));
        }
    }
}
```

And the JS code to call it:

```
var obj = new Test2.Class1();
obj.testAccess();
```

And have you also confirmed that the logo.png file is in your JS project?

Comment: Hi, yes i am able to access the images folder, but i have another folder "www" in which there is a subfolder "img" and when i am trying to access images using Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///www/img/logo.png")); it gives error. Can we access only the root folders and not the subfolders?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem...using images/ you're already going into a subfolder of the package. One thing: in Visual Studio, right click logo.png and select Properties. In the pane that appears below the Solution Explorer pane, check what it says for "Package Action". If this is "None" then the image won't be copied with the package; it needs to be "Content".